# Executing Jquery function inside angular expression

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Is it possible to execute JQuery inside Angular expression? Below is the example:

```
<span>{{$("[for='loanType']").text()}}</span>
```

I tried it but so far it's not possible. Is there a work around to make it work? Else, I have to create a key/value pair variable for this which I don't like.

Comment: nope................

Comment: the best you could do is [this from this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qn1v2oMqgAIC6zVEdQf8?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid adding extra code in js side.. :)

Comment: Why don't you set the loanType to an ng-model instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this. In the Controller I created a function that executes a Jquery function:

```
   public GetFormLabelText(fieldName: string): string{
        return $("[for='" + fieldName + "']").text();
    }
```

Now I can call this function in my page:

```
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="r in myForm.$error.required">
         {{ViewModel.GetFormLabelText(r.$name)}} is required.
     </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="r in myForm.$error.number">
         {{ViewModel.GetFormLabelText(r.$name)}} must be a number.
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="r in myForm.$error.max">
         {{ViewModel.GetFormLabelText(r.$name)}} is out of range.
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Pretty neat. Thanks for all the comments! :)